# jQuery - slideToggle() and Toggle Text

Tags: jquery

I have a contact form that can be hidden using `.slideToggle()` but I want the tab used to `Toggle` the form to change text based on wether the form is `in view` or `hidden`.

Here is the jQuery:

```
$("#slider").click(function() {
  $("#form_wrap").animate({ opacity: 1.0 },200).slideToggle();
});
```

I want the text of `#slider` to read 'Hide' then 'Show'.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Something like this would work:

```
$("#slider").click(function() {
  $("#form_wrap").animate({ opacity: 1.0 },200).slideToggle(500, function() {
    $("#slider").text($(this).is(':visible') ? "Hide" : "Show");
  });
});
```

I assume here the tab you're clicking `#slider` is what you want to change the text of, your question confuses me a bit on that part.  Once the animation is complete, this sets the text of the button depending on the visibility state of `#form_wrap` at the end.