# jQuery toggle and changing text

Tags: jquery, slidetoggle

**jQuery**

```
$('#message div').hide();
    $('.readmore').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#message div').slideToggle();
    });
```

**html**

```
<div id="message">
    <p class="intro">This is an introduction.</p>
            <div>
            <p>This is the first paragraph thats orginally hidden</p>
        <p>This is the second paragraph</p>
            </div>
            <a href="#" class="readmore">Read More</a>
        </div><!--message-->
```

When the read more button is clicked the content is slideToggled and shows to everyone and clicked again it hides to only show my .intro but I would like to toggle the Read More text between Read More and Show Less.

How is this possible whilst using slideToggle

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery - slideToggle() and Toggle Text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2586156/jquery-slidetoggle-and-toggle-text)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Check the text of current element inside its click event and use condition, see if you have to change the text if yes, change it using `text()` again ;).

Try this:

```
 $('.readmore').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#message div').slideToggle();
    $(this).text( $(this).text() == 'Read More' ? "Show Less" : "Read More"); // using ternary operator.
});
```

Comment: Please not that this might be problem in if you do localisation

Answer (score 0):

There is a **minor amendment** in the code because the above code did not work for me. I have **Read More** text with space on the left-right side so the ternary operator fails to recognize it. I added **$.(trim)** to make it **work**.

```
$('.readmore').click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
$('#message div').slideToggle();
$(this).text( $.trim($(this).text()) == 'Read More' ? "Show Less" : "Read More"); // using ternary operator.
});
```